# .htaccess Rewrite non-www to www except specific dynamic pages

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I've looked through the myriad of answers here and elsewhere but not found exactly what I need.. I'm working with and old Joomla 1.5 site, not using SEF by the owners specific request. But I want all non-www requests to be rewritten to www except specific form / payment pages.

```
Example: 
http://domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=43&Itemid=11 
becomes
http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=43&Itemid=11
except a payment page
http://domain.com/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=3
or 
http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=3
becomes
https://domain.com/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=3
```

I'm using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Redirect non-https non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
########## End - Redirect non-www to www
```

This gets me there as long as they stick with my link to the payment pages, but I'd like to fool-proof it. And get a better understanding of how to do it. I've tired maybe a hundred different rules -I'm trying to learn the regex issues, but can't get it in time for my client.

I can do with it working on any form so "option=com_rsform" would always be in the url. I don't know if that is treated as a string or variable when making a condition.. anyway I would really appreciate a suggested solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Redirect non-https non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^option=com_rsform&formId=3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
########## End - Redirect non-www to www

# payment URL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_rsform&formId=3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for an amazing quick reply! In this case I'd have to add each form to both sections?

Comment: Yes both rules will need to check for presence and absence of that query string. Also make sure these rules are first rules. Going offline now.

Comment: ok, but this doesn't work for the last case in my question:
    https://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=3
    should become
    https://domain.com/..

Comment: yes , no other rewrite. When I said it doesn't work I meant it gives a security exception and then doesn't remove the "www" it does add https. but part of the point is to avoid the security exception, which I didn't mention in the original post. My apologies.

Comment: SSL cert negotiation happen before rewrite rules. So if your cert is for www host and you open a URL with non-www then cert warning will still show up.